# Generate image having text with user's First Name and Last Name initials

Tags: laravel, intervention

I want every user to have a default profile image when they register. This *image will have initial letter of their First Name and Last Name.*

I made a plain image with a single color, I then tried to write text on it using Intervention Image. It works, but **font size is too small I can't increase it**. I don't know what's the max font size in Intervention, as documentation says nothing about it.
I also tried with different font, put the font in a font folder and I refer it in `$font->file('font/Poppins.ttf')`. It throws an error `'Undefined Offset'`.

**RegisterController.php**

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $img = Image::make('storage/avatars/1.jpg');
    $img->text('HW', 125, 80, function ($font) {
        $font->file('font/Poppins.ttf');
        $font->size(40);
        $font->color('#fdf6e3');
        $font->align('center');
        $font->angle(45);
    });
    $filename = time().'.'.'jpg';
    $img->resize(150, 150)->save('storage/avatars/'.$filename);

    return User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'avatar' => $filename,
    ]);
}
```

**I have a default image which has only red color as background. Whenever a person register he must have this image as default profile picture with his First Name and Last Name's initial letters on it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving the correct path to the font.ttf file

change this

```
$font->file('font/Poppins.ttf');
```

to this

```
 $font->file(public_path('/fonts/font.ttf'));
```

Comment: Try placing it in public/fonts/ folder and call it like `$font->file(public_path('/fonts/font.ttf'))`

Comment: It works. But I can't increase font size. What's the max font size?

Comment: Can you check what image size it is generating without the resize? Your font-size should be 60-70% image dimensions, like if your image is 100px; font-size of 60px would be fine.

Comment: The size that we give in `$font->size(40)`. Is **40** here in pixels?

Comment: Yes, it is in pixels.